# Setup simple Automation system using Email

Tags: email, imap

Trying to setup a simple automation system has proved exceedingly complicated for me. Using scripts, I want to use email to perform remote tasks. The script outline:

1. Send an empty body email with the header as "Pattern1 (number)"
2. Read the last 50 email headers.
3. Find latest header matching "Pattern2 (number)".
4. Save (echo) the number from that header into a file.
5. Wait 5 minutes
6. Loop to 1.

I'm trying to using as few programs as possible. Currently, have Mutt for email sending and retrieval. And grepmail (with grepm script) for searching emails.

Am I way off on using Mutt and grepmail? I'm confused as a non-sysadmin. Mutt isn't great for scripting. What's the simplest way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can all be done with only `curl`.

Send email

```
MSG="From: a@gmail.com
To: Receiver
Subject: Test"

echo "$MSG" | curl --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --ssl-reqd \
--mail-from "a@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "receiver@gmail.com" \
--upload-file - --user "a@gmail.com:password" --insecure
```

To read mail, first you have to know how many emails are in the INBOX.

```
EXISTS="$(curl --insecure \
--user "a@gmail.com:password" \
--url 'imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/' \
--request "EXAMINE INBOX" | grep "EXISTS" | grep -oP '\d*' | head -n1 )"

echo "$EXISTS"
```

The newest email has the highest number. Print the subject of the last 5 emails, newest first.

```
for ((i=$EXISTS;i!=$EXISTS-5;i--)); do
   SUBJECT="$(curl --insecure -u "a@gmail.com:password" \
   --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX;UID=$i" | \
   grep "Subject: " | head -n1 )"

   echo "$SUBJECT"
done
```

Notice: To enable smtp/imap access like this, you must go into gmail settings disable secure settings.